# Am I using the proper predicate for my lambda?

Tags: javascript, lambda

I've been working on this program for a few hours, and I finally got it to output - NaN. I dont know how this could be, I'm pushing a product of real numbers into the array... Somebody help! What did I miss? The problem is to find the largest product produced by 13 adjacent digits within the 1000 digit number assigned to _1000digits.

```js
// what is the largest product of 13 adjacent digits within this 1000 digit number
function largestProduct() {
  _1000digits = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450;
  separateDigits = _1000digits.toString().split("");
  products = [];
  var a = 0;
  var b = 1;
  var c = 2;
  var d = 3;
  var e = 4;
  var f = 5;
  var g = 6;
  var h = 7;
  var i = 8;
  var j = 9;
  var k = 10;
  var l = 11;
  var m = 12;
  while (m <= 999) {
    products.push(
      separateDigits[a] *
        separateDigits[b] *
        separateDigits[c] *
        separateDigits[d] *
        separateDigits[e] *
        separateDigits[f] *
        separateDigits[g] *
        separateDigits[h] *
        separateDigits[i] *
        separateDigits[j] *
        separateDigits[k] *
        separateDigits[l] *
        separateDigits[m]
    );
    a++;
    b++;
    c++;
    d++;
    e++;
    f++;
    g++;
    h++;
    i++;
    j++;
    k++;
    l++;
    m++;
  }
  products.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  console.log(products.pop());
}

largestProduct();
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short:**

To work with such huge numbers you'll want to use a special data structure, like [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt).

**Long:**

There are a few issues with your code, the first one is trying to store such a huge number in a variable without any treatment. A JavaScript `number` can only store values up to 25^3 - 1, your number is a lot bigger than that.

If you run:

```js
_1000digits = 7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
console.log(_1000digits)
```

You'll see the output is "Infinity" because that's such a huge number JavaScript doesn't know how to store it entirely.

You're also not checking if the numbers you're accessing actually exist, so if you put a smaller number in `_1000digits` you'll end up multiplying by `undefined`, which will result in `NaN`:

```js
_1000digits = 700
separateDigits = _1000digits.toString().split("")
var f = 5
console.log(separateDigits[f])
```